# created_at, modified_at, status - is this a documented pattern?

Tags: database-design

I am but a lowly code monkey, so this may be a very basic question.

For the current project, our architect has required that *all* tables, without exception, must have at least these four fields:

```
`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
`created_at` TIMESTAMP,
`modified_at` TIMESTAMP,
`status` INT COMMENT "-1=delete using cron, 0=disabled so only admins can see it, 1=active"
```

This last field is the one I do not understand. To me, it flies in the face of every normal kind of database design.

- It breaks SELECT: every single select must do a full table scan on
  status to see if it's 1, for every table involved in the join.
- It breaks UNIQUE KEY. Any time a table has a unique key, then
  deleting an entry prevents that entry being recreated until cron has
  run - which he was saying could be any amount of time, even "three
  months".

  Any time I do a check against, for example, username existence, for
  someone creating a new username, I must check all data *including
  deleted entries*, rather than just active data, because the unique
  key would prevent creation even though there's no valid record using
  that value.
- It breaks ON DELETE. When something is marked "disabled" or
  "deleted", all its cascadable items must have that status cascaded
  through code: the database can't do it for us.
- It seems to violate normalization, as it gloms a few different
  concerns (admin vs user visibility; garbage collection) into a single
  field.
- It is also a criminally poor choice of field name, far too ambiguous. What does it *mean*?

And that's just the problems I've found so far.

The main assumption here seems to be that DELETE is "expensive", and must be optimized for. But deletions on this system will be extraordinarily rare (<1/month), and the overwhelming majority of operations will be SELECTs (several/second) or INSERTS (several/min).

While looking for other questions on this, I did find
[What could be causing strange query timeouts between PHP and MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7218/what-could-be-causing-strange-query-timeouts-between-php-and-mysql) that suggests that there are people using these fields for some tables at least.

But all tables? Including many-many link tables?

The advantages he cites are that it allows things to be easily dis/enabled, and undeleted if they were deleted by accident.

Except that it doesn't. None of the connected systems are able to handle something being temporarily disabled: either it's active, or it's deleted. The deletion of any entity is typically accompanied by API calls to notify other systems of the deletion, and so cannot easily be resurrected just by changing the value of a field on our own DB.

So my question is - is this a standard DB architecture decision? If so, what's it called, and is it documented anywhere, so I can wrap my head around why such an apparently-broken design pattern would ever be useful?

Comment: I shared my take on a [similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107575/63644) before. I don't know if this one is a duplicate, so if you consider that it actually is, please mark it as a such.

Comment: You might find [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36558/implementing-soft-delete) and [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/tombstone-table-vs-deleted-flag-in-database-syncronization-soft-delete-scenari) helpful. Spoiler: it is a common pattern, but like most things, it can depend a lot on your needs. I personally loathe using negative `INT` for statuses, though. You might also be interested in [Slowly Changing Dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension).

Comment: Given you have an interaction with other systems, it's important to make clear the potential impact on those other systems. If they are expected to work with "deleted" or "disabled" rows, then they need to be able to support this scheme as well. Positive thought - include `status` in the primary key (after the actual key, ideally), and the cascading aspect of things may take care of itself....

Comment: So far, it's looking like the answer for the question I asked is "this is a Soft Delete; an alternative to Tombstone tables, a poor-man's alternative to comprehensive auditing, and an extension to merely marking records as disabled". The question I probably _meant_ to ask is probably a duplicate of the SO question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549839/are-soft-deletes-a-good-idea".